# Android Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy() always return true

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I build a small app, compiling it with compileSdkVersion 29, targetSdkVersion 29, in app's AndroidManifest.xml I either specify

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false"
```

or remove it completely. I *uninstall* the app from Android 10 emulator (latest version of emulator that comes with Android Studio). Then install and check Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy(); it *always* returns true. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the reason: I AndroidManifest.xml I was also using:

```
android:sharedUserId="some.package.name.shared"
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/some_uuid_name"
```

and other legacy mode apps were still installed. Removing sharedUserId (or I guess, uninstalling other legacy apps that share the ID) fixes the problem.